# zeep connection over https

Tags: python-3.x, soap, suds, zeep

I had a python 2.7 code which was using suds to connect to webservice. But i am trying to upgrade it to python 3 and suds was not working for many of reasons. so thought of using zeep
My suds code goes here:

```
t = suds.transport.https.HttpAuthenticated(**creds)
client=suds.client.Client(url,location=loc,transport=t)
return client
```

How do i convert this to zeep. Especially giving https urls (I dont have a certificate) and giving location url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both suds and zeep should work on Python 3, so you shouldn't need to "convert" your code to zeep.

Why specifically is suds not working for you? On Python 3, suds has a different package name, suds-py3. Have you tried "pip install suds-py3" instead of "pip install suds"?